# How to compare a string as a variable to an another variable string?

Tags: c++, input

So, I want to get an answer from the user (Yes or No), and if it's yes do someting, and if no, do something else.

I'm using c++ (with Code::Blocks), and I'm a beginner at programming.
This is what I managed to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char answer;
answer = 1;
int x;
x = 1;
int number1;
while ( x > 0 )
{  //Ez egy köszönés!
cout<<"Type in a number!\n";
 //Kérek egy számot
cin>> number1;
  cin.ignore();
 //Kiírom a számot
  cout<<"You entered: "<< number1 <<"\n";
if ( number1 == 666 )  //Ha number1 = 666 akkor kiírjuk hogy Are you the Devil?
{
    cout<<"Are you the Devil?\n";
    x = 0;
}
if ( number1 != 666 )
{
if ( number1 > 5 ) //Ha number1 nagyobb 5nél kiírjuk hogy Great Job!
{
      cout<<"Great job!\n";
}
if ( number1 < 5  )  //Ha number1 kisebb 5nél kiírjuk hogy Good Job!
{
      cout<<"Good job!\n";
}
if ( number1 == 5 )  //Ha number1 = 5 akkor kiírjuk hogy Thank you
{
    cout<<"Thank You\n";
}
}

cout<<"\n"; //sortörés
}
cin>> answer;
if ( answer == 1 )
{
    cout<<"OH GOD,NO!";
}
}
```

It suposed to ask for a number, if you give it one if it's less tan 5 it would say:Good Job!, if more Great Job!, if 5 Thank you, and do it in a loop.
And if you type in 666 it would ask if you're devil.and here I want to get an input from the user, Yes or No. if No then it would say: OH GOD,NO, if Yes, well I didn't got there yet...

Comment: I don't see you comparing *strings* anywhere, only integers and a character. And regarding that character comparison, how do you normally write character literals? Think a little about the difference between e.g. the number `1` and the character `'1'`.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. As to the answer, try inputting a string wariable: `std::string yesNo; cin>>yesNo;`

Comment: If you have an instructor please go to them and get some help.  There are a LOT of issues with this code.  Beginner misunderstanding stuff that your teacher should be able to help with.

Comment: If you are testing for two alternatives in an `if`-statement, there is a very useful `else`-part you can use to simplify the code. Also, values of type `char` are written with single quotes, like `'1'`. `1` and `'1'` are totally different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idiom for confirmation from a User:

```
std::string answer;
std::cin >> answer;
// Convert to all lower case to reduce number of compares.
// Text is case-sensitive.
std::transform(answer.begin(), answer.end(),
               answer.begin(),
               std::tolower());

// Now compare
if (answer == "no")
{
 // ...
}
```

For beginners, a simpler solution may be to ask for a single character response:

```
std::cout << "Continue, Y/N?";
std::cout.flush();
char response;
std::cin >> response;
response = std::toupper(response);
if (response == 'Y')
{
 //...
}
```

**Edit 1: case sensitivity**
In C++, capital letters are different than lower case letters.
So for example, "No" is different than "nO".
If you don't convert the string to one case (all lower or all upper), you will have to check each permuation:  "no", "nO", "NO", "No".  The quantity is worse for "yes".
To reduce the number of comparisons, convert the string to all upper or all lower before comparing.